# Нужно чтобы тело змейки вело себя как веревка

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
       private Quaternion _initialRotation;
       private Rigidbody _rb;

        void Start()
        {
         _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        }
    
        void FixedUpdate()
        {
         PhysicsMove();
        }
    
        void PhysicsMove()
        {
           transform.rotation = _initialRotation;
           _rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 10);

           if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
           {
               _rb.AddForce(-transform.right * 400);
           }
           if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
           {
               _rb.AddForce(transform.right * 400);
           }
        }
```

Так реализовано движение головы змеи

подскажите как реализовать движение ячеек хвоста чтобы они были похожи по физике на веревку которую волокут вслед за головой

Пробовал поколдовать с настройками Fixed Joint и
Character Joint, но хвост смотрит всегда вверх теперь.

[image]

Comment: С помощью `Join` компонентов.

Comment: @ИльяВодопьянов давайте без сарказма